# php upload file class

Tags: php, file, class, upload

i am new to php
i am in search of a php function in a class that accepts some parameters like size,type etc 
the class should be such that it should be able to set some default values to the parameters that are not assigned by user for ex the destination folder etc
can anybody give me a link or some hint how should i do this

Comment: This is very, very hazy. Can you start over and explain in more detail what exactly you want to do?

Comment: i dont understand what you exactly want

Comment: i downloaded one class from phpclasses.org, it has all functionality like uploading a file,image,limiting the size etc,now for that we need to pass different variables to all the functions,i want that only one function,to contain all the functionality of uploading a file. so that i can use that function any where i want

Comment: And while you're at it, please add some punctuation :) No one wants to read a four line sentence

Comment: So you want a function with all the functionality of the class?

Answer (score 0):

You create a class, then you add some fields to it. Set the default values in the constructor and you're good to go.
For added encapsulation, you can define a __get() and __set() method and then make the fields private so they cannot be modified from outside your class directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try PEAR. 
http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Upload/redirected